# Running tests in a container on Travis

Tags: node.js, docker, travis-ci

While building my application on Travis I am trying to run the tests within a Docker container. The container starts and the tests are run, and when I log the container output I can see they have passed. It is my understanding I can use grep for this as seen below. So this is my travis script:

script:

- docker-compose up -d
- docker logs dockertestapp_app_1
- docker logs 2>&1 dockertestapp_app_1 | grep -q 'npm info ok'

I just want to grep the output of the container logs to see whether or not the tests pass but it always fails. Am I missing something simple?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For anybody who ends up here with the same problem, I discovered my issue. travis was executing the docker logs 2>... statement too quickly so my tests were still actually running and so of course it would fail. To combat this I added a simple sleep 60 to my travis script.

Comment: This could delay your tests running time. There may be a better approach. Maybe getting inside Docker container to run tests. I'll publish an answer if anything comes up to my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid a sleep of 60 seconds you described in your comment, start your tests manually doing something like this:

`docker exec -it dockertestapp_app_1 bash -c 'tests.py > /proc/1/fd/1'`

Note I'm executing a test file (in this example, `tests.py`) and setting output to `/proc/1/fd/1`. This way you can normally grep the expression that means your tests passed as you are currently doing.

**TIP**: you may not need to output to `/proc/1/fd/1` for docker logs as your test script may return a non-zero exit code to indicate that tests failed. This way you don't even need the grep line in your script.

Comment: This is a much better way to handle my problem. While it means the builds are longer it also does not cater for test suites which run longer than 60 seconds. I had not thought of entering the container and reading the feedback. Thank you.